# Lubuntu screen resolution

Tags: lubuntu, display, display-resolution

I have something strange going on with my screen resolution:

[image: Screenshot]

How can I fix this? Panel has resolution 1366x768, but desktop and all windows has 1024x768.

Answer (score -1):

Need to see your conf file of vncserver. In this file mast be screen resolution. It mast be in /etc/vncserver/
Try to connect by vncx11.
sudo apt-get install x11vnc  (install x11vnc as aoolication)
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/x11vnc.service  (create demon)

[Unit]
Description=Start x11vnc at startup.
After=multi-user.target
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -auth guess -forever -loop -noxdamage -repeat -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc.pass -rfbport 5900 -shared
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

sudo x11vnc -storepasswd 111111 /etc/x11vnc.pass (this line make pass for connect 111111)

sudo systemctl daemon-reload   (make reload all demons )
sudo systemctl enable x11vnc.service (enable service)

Reboot your system and try to connect (host or ip with port 59000 (192.168.1.5:590000) )